# AngularJS Service not acting as Singleton

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, amplitude-analytics

Apologies for the code heavy post but I wanted to provide as much context as possible. I am having an issue with defining a service in my Angular.js application. Services are supposed to act as singletons throughout an application ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)), so I am very confused to be getting the following behavior.

In my **app.js** file, I run my **AmplitudeService** Service and console.log(AmplitudeService). This outputs an object with all of the methods that I have defined within my AmplitudeService.js file. As such, I am able to properly use the service and log events as expected.

However, when I console.log(AmplitudeService) within my **header.js**, it outputs my Window object. As such, the Window does not contain functions such as "logEvent", "identifyUser", etc., so **AmplitudeService** is not usable in that case.

Would appreciate any and all insight!

**AmplitudeService.js** ([source](https://github.com/mounibec/angular-amplitude))

Note: If you check the author's syntax, he returns an object at the end of his service. In my research, I've read to use the "this" keyword when defining Service functions ([source](http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/#comment-20762)), and that you don't need to return an object as you would with a Factory, so I have updated it accordingly.

```
angular.module('AmplitudeService', [])
.service('AmplitudeService', 
['$amplitude', '$rootScope', 'amplitudeApiKey', '$location',
 function ($amplitude, $rootScope, amplitudeApiKey, $location) {

  this.init = function() {
    $amplitude.init(amplitudeApiKey, null);
    $amplitude.logEvent('LAUNCHED_SITE', {page: $location.$$path});
  }

  this.identifyUser = function(userId, userProperties) {
    $amplitude.setUserId(userId);
    $amplitude.setUserProperties(userProperties);
  }

  this.logEvent = function(eventName, params) {
    $amplitude.logEvent(eventName, params);
  }
}]);
```

**angular-amplitude.js** ([source](https://github.com/mounibec/angular-amplitude))

This allows access to "$amplitude" throughout the application

```
(function(){
var module = angular.module('angular-amplitude', ['ng']);

module.provider('$amplitude', [function $amplitudeProvider() {
    this.$get = ['$window', function($window) {
      (function(e,t){
        var r = e.amplitude || {};
        var n = t.createElement("script");
        n.type = "text/javascript";
      n.async = true;
      n.src = "https://d24n15hnbwhuhn.buttfront.net/libs/amplitude-2.2.0-min.gz.js";
      var s = t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(n,s);
      r._q = [];

      function a(e){
        r[e] = function(){
          r._q.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)));
        }
      }
      var i = ["init","logEvent","logRevenue","setUserId","setUserProperties","setOptOut","setVersionName","setDomain","setDeviceId","setGlobalUserProperties"];
      for(var o = 0; o < i.length; o++){
        a(i[o])
      }
      e.amplitude = r
    }
      )(window,document);
      return $window.amplitude;
    }];
}]);
return module;
}());
```

**App.js**

```
angular.module('app', [
'ngRoute',
'angular-amplitude',
'AmplitudeService',
])

 .run(['AmplitudeService', function(AmplitudeService){
 console.log(AmplitudeService); // Outputs 'Object {}'
 AmplitudeService.init();
 AmplitudeService.logEvent('LAUNCHED_SITE');
 console.log(AmplitudeService); // Outputs 'Object {}'
 }])
```

**Header.js**

```
angular.module('app.common.header', [])
.controller('HeaderCtrl', [ '$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$scope', '$route', '$window', 'AmplitudeService', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $route, $window, AmplitudeService){

$scope.goToSearch = function(term) {
$location.path('/search/' + term);
 console.log(AmplitudeService); // Outputs 'Window {}'
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are injecting `$scope` in your controller, causing the unexpected mapping of the variable

```
angular.module('app.common.header', [])
.controller('HeaderCtrl', [ '$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', **'$scope'**, '$route', '$window', 'AmplitudeService', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $route, $window, AmplitudeService){

$scope.goToSearch = function(term) {
$location.path('/search/' + term);
 console.log(AmplitudeService); // Outputs 'Window {}'
};
}]);
```

as an aside if find this format far easier to read / work with when defining controllers

```
angular
  .module('app.common.header', [])
  .controller('HeaderCtrl', headerController);

headerController.$inject = [ '$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$route', '$window', 'AmplitudeService']

function headerController($rootScope, $scope, $location, $route, $window, AmplitudeService){
  $scope.goToSearch = function(term) {
    $location.path('/search/' + term);
    console.log(AmplitudeService); // Outputs 'Window {}'
  };
}
```

Comment: I think I need $scope, but I could be wrong. All of my functions (which I have stripped to cut down the amount of code in this post) within Header.js are listed as $scope functions. For example, $scope.goToSearch(term) would go to my Search page and search for the term. This function is called in the HTML using ng-submit = "goToSearch(term)".

Comment: I have removed the $scope injection, but now I have 7 undefined functions within that controller. Any other suggestions? I appreciate the previous comment.

Comment: You have injected `$scope` twice - have a look where I have added the `**'$scope'**` in your example (first code sample). Remove this definition and you should be good to go.

Comment: Angular doesn't care about the names of the functions, it maps them in the order they are defined i.e.`['$scope', function(a){console.log(a)}]` a in this instance will be $scope

Comment: Wow, unreal. You are totally right and I am now getting the expected behavior. Thank you so much.

Comment: curious if you could provide any insight here? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421245/angularjs-amplitude-service-not-acting-as-singleton