# AngularJS Amplitude Service Not Acting as Singleton

Tags: angularjs, singleton, analytics, angularjs-service, amplitude-analytics

I have recently posted a similar question, but this is not a duplicate.
Apologies for the code heavy post but I wanted to provide as much context as possible. I am having an issue with defining the analytics tool, 'Amplitude' as a service in my Angular.js application. Services are supposed to act as singletons throughout an application ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)), so I am confused to be getting the following behavior.

In my **app.js** file, I call AmplitudeService.logEvent('EVENT_NAME') in a .run function which successfully logs the event to Amplitude. **Note:** Console.log(AmplitudeService) returns an object with all the correct functions here.

However, when I call AmplitudeService.logEvent('EVENT_NAME') within any other controller, such as **header.js** I do not ever see any data in my Amplitude dashboard. **Note:** Console.log(AmplitudeService) returns an identical object within **header.js** to the one returned from **app.js**

Would appreciate any and all insight!

P.S. The official [AmplitudeJS SDK is here](https://github.com/amplitude/Amplitude-Javascript). I am trying to implement it through this [wrapper](https://github.com/mounibec/angular-amplitude).

**AmplitudeService.js** ([source](https://github.com/mounibec/angular-amplitude))

Note: If you check the author's syntax, he returns an object at the end of his service. In my research, I've read to use the "this" keyword when defining Service functions ([source](http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/#comment-20762)), and that you don't need to return an object as you would with a Factory, so I have updated it accordingly.

```
angular.module('AmplitudeService', [])
.service('AmplitudeService', 
['$amplitude', '$rootScope', 'amplitudeApiKey', '$location',
function ($amplitude, $rootScope, amplitudeApiKey, $location) {

  this.init = function() {
    $amplitude.init(amplitudeApiKey, null);
  }

  this.identifyUser = function(userId, userProperties) {
    $amplitude.setUserId(userId);
    $amplitude.setUserProperties(userProperties);
  }

  this.logEvent = function(eventName, params) {
    $amplitude.logEvent(eventName, params);
  }
}]);
```

**angular-amplitude.js** ([source](https://github.com/mounibec/angular-amplitude))

This allows access to "$amplitude" throughout the application

```
(function(){
var module = angular.module('angular-amplitude', ['ng']);

module.provider('$amplitude', [function $amplitudeProvider() {
this.$get = ['$window', function($window) {
  (function(e,t){
    var r = e.amplitude || {};
    var n = t.createElement("script");
    n.type = "text/javascript";
  n.async = true;
  n.src = "https://d24n15hnbwhuhn.buttfront.net/libs/amplitude-2.2.0-min.gz.js";
  var s = t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(n,s);
  r._q = [];

  function a(e){
    r[e] = function(){
      r._q.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)));
    }
  }
  var i =    ["init","logEvent","logRevenue","setUserId","setUserProperties","setOptOut","setVersionName","setDomain","setDeviceId","setGlobalUserProperties"];
  for(var o = 0; o < i.length; o++){
    a(i[o])
  }
  e.amplitude = r
}
  )(window,document);
  return $window.amplitude;
}];
}]);
return module;
}());
```

**App.js**

```
angular.module('app', [
'ngRoute',
'angular-amplitude',
'AmplitudeService',
])

 .run(['AmplitudeService', function(AmplitudeService){
 console.log(AmplitudeService); // Outputs 'Object {}'
 AmplitudeService.init();
 *AmplitudeService.logEvent('LAUNCHED_SITE'); // This logs the event*
 console.log(AmplitudeService); // Outputs 'Object {}'
 }])
```

**Header.js**

```
  angular.module('app.common.header', [])
 .controller('HeaderCtrl', [ '$rootScope', '$scope', '$location','$route', '$window', 'AmplitudeService', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $route, $window, AmplitudeService){

 $scope.goToSearch = function(term) {
 $location.path('/search/' + term);
  console.log(AmplitudeService); // Outputs 'Object {}'
*AmplitudeService.logEvent('SEARCHED');* // This does not log the event
 };
 }]);
```

Update: I have tried switching the Service to a Factory and that did not generate any new results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution and hope this is helpful to anyone that comes across this. My solution was to initialize the SDK by calling AmplitudeService.init() within a .run() function within app.js, which initialized an amplitude object within my window. From there forward, I included $window as a service in each of my controllers and called $window.amplitude.logEvent('event_name_here');

Feel free to contact if you have questions. Thanks.

Comment: Right, I'm working on Angular Universal and importing amp from 'amplitude-js'; but it's not working. an error like : [Amplitude] Error thrown when checking for cookies. Reason: "Error: NotYetImplemented"
optionoptionoption ::> null
ERROR Error: NotYetImplemented

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues on a large project and we created a [wrapper providing a directive](https://github.com/gregorifaroux/angular-amplitudejs) to init Amplitude and a service to provide the logEvent and sendUserId.